# Open URL on phone from watch face

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a watch face that I've created and I was looking into adding an "About" screen in the watch settings (on the watch). This screen would show the current version and show a button to open a URL leading to a changelog. I want the user to be able to click the button on their watch, and have it open the specified URL on the phone.

Is this possible without me creating a mobile companion application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this if the watch is running Android Wear 2 using a `RemoteIntent`, as such:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
                .setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));

RemoteIntent.startRemoteActivity(context, intent, null);
```

...replacing `http://www.google.com` with your desired URL, of course.

AFAIK, there's no way to accomplish this on Wear 1.x without sending a message to your handheld app and programming it to open the URL itself.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Do you know if/how to use the "Opening on Phone" animation for RemoteIntents?

Comment: @Nxt3 check my answer for how to show the open on phone animation

Answer (score 1):

Note the new way to do this is with [RemoteActivityHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/remote/interactions/RemoteActivityHelper):

```
    val remoteActivityHelper = RemoteActivityHelper(context, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
    val result = remoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity(
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
          .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
          .setData(
            Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/")
          ),
        null
    )
```

and if you want to show the nice "Open on phone" animation, use [ConfirmationActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/activity/ConfirmationActivity):

```
   startActivity(
      Intent(this, ConfirmationActivity::class.java)
        .putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_TYPE, ConfirmationActivity.OPEN_ON_PHONE_ANIMATION))
```